# Browser cache expiration for js and css files with wildfly

Tags: angularjs, wildfly, cache-control, etag

I have a angularjs javascript app packaged in a webapp deployed to Wildfly 8.2.1.
Sometimes, when I deploy javascript or css modifications to this webapp, users have to manually delete their browser cache for the modifications appear.
Is there a way to change this behavior so users don't have to delete their browser cache every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've shared a Gist [article](https://gist.github.com/remibantos/5e86829e1ba6ad64eea1) about that.

It describes how to configure response headers in wildfly undertow subsytem to tune expiration cache headers in server http response, for specific static contents such as .js, .css, ... files.

Comment: Its nice to share how to configure cache expiration, although it makes your clients possibly download many many times the same resources. I would try to go with HTTP ETag but do not know how to configure this for Wildfly. I found this interesting info no strictly addressing your question as it relates to JAX-RS with Wildfly and Etag. [HTTP Caching in Practice DEVOXX'13 Quickie](https://github.com/xcoulon/devoxx13-quickie)

Comment: Will take a look about ETag, thanks. For the cache-control setting, I think it is a common practice. For example, I've noticed such headers in github pages http responses, so same static contents are downloaded many times but with a minimum delay of 10 minutes between each requests.